# Force overwrite file when exporting using excel

Tags: vbscript

How do I make it so that if a file with the same name already exists, it will be quietly overwritten?

```
Dim oExcel
Dim oBook
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))

'What options to add?
oBook.SaveAs "out.csv", 6

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.DisplayAlerts = False` to turn such questions off.

Comment: Where do I put this? When I write it on its own line, I get a "Invalid or unqualified reference". Note that I save the script as `.vbs` and just let windows figure out what to use. Not sure if I should run it differently.

Comment: @Keikoku - didn't you see it used in the code of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20382898/603855

Comment: ah, that's what you meant by the leading `.`