# VB script excel.exe process termination

Tags: excel, vbscript, taskmanager

I have written a VB script wherein I am opening an excel file, running a macro, saving the file and then closing it.

There is a problem however, there are many "Excel.exe" getting clogged up in this process.
Apparently, this is a common problem and saw the same post everywhere.

One person solved it using :

```
oWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:= False
```

But when I used this in my code it throws an error at this line. Maybe this is because I want to save and am saving it before the above line.

My code :

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Pravin.Singh\Desktop\Marketing Vehicle Forecast_10302014_RB_fv.xlsm")

Set xlSheet = xlBook.worksheets.item(1)

xlApp.Run "Refresh_Report"
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close 
xlApp.Quit

Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Set nothing is done here and closing all objects and excel is also done.

what else needs to be done here to prevent this "Excel.exe" clogging process?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21206112/603855 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20382898/603855

Comment: Named parameters are allowed only in VBA, in VBS use the syntax: `xlBook.Close False`.