# ASP classic: Catch then throw error to usual handler

Tags: error-handling, asp-classic

I want to capture and log some more detail on an occasional error, but then I need the code to proceed with its existing behavior when the error is encountered (which I think involves forwarding to a 500.100 handler).

```
FUNCTION ConvertDate(TheDate)
    ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
    Err.Clear
    ConvertDate = YEAR(TheDate) & "-" & NumberLength(MONTH(TheDate),2) & "-" & NumberLength(DAY(TheDate),2)
    IF Err.Number <> 0 THEN
        myErrorLogger TheDate
        ' *** Wanted here: Now handle this error in the usual way ***
    END IF
    ON ERROR GOTO 0
END FUNCTION
```

What can I put in the inner-most loop to cause the normal response to an error after I've logged my notes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I throw an error in vbscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503170/can-i-throw-an-error-in-vbscript)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate.