# What is the maximum number of arguments that can be passed in a Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, vbscript, arguments, parameter-passing, runtime.exec

I'm trying to pass a good number of arguments to a `Runtime.().exec`:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { executable, script, fnamePath, blah, blah, .... });
```

And the script after adding 12th argument says:

> Error:    Subscript out of range
>   Code: 800A0009

Can you please let me know what is the best way to pass **mass arguments**? Or, please rectify my method to achieve passing mass arguments.

Please let me know if any further details required...

VBS code:

```vb
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
myMail.Attachments.Add Arg(0) 'Just to let you know I'm using the Arg(0) as well
IMED = Arg(1)
URL = Arg(2)
dashLoad = Arg(3)
roles = Arg(4)
consent = Arg(5)
dash = Arg(6)
servMenu = Arg(7)
folowUp = Arg(8)
servReq = Arg(9)
SRN = Arg(10)
PoP = Arg(11)
Doc = Arg(12)
SalesDashLoad = Arg(13)
MsgBox (SalesDashLoad) ' THIS LINE gives me error, till Agr(12) works fine!
```

Executing above VBS in Java:
[image: Runtime Method in Java]

Resultant Error msg:

[image: VBS Error]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look like it's VBScript in the first place. For help with a VBScript error you need to show your VBScript code (more specifically a [mcve] of it).

Comment: You say *"after the 12th argument"* but from VBScript code, it's expecting 14 arguments *(as the collection starts at `0`)*. You need to check you are passing 14 arguments or `Arg(13)` will fail with the `Subscript out of range` error. Go back and check you have 14 arguments being passed in.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on passed arguments, but that isn't the issue.

You need to remember that the Java call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is first firing the VBScript Hosted executable *(might be `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`)* and passing the script file path to execute, this takes up two arguments in the command array you send to `exec()`.

From the screenshot after the `executable` and `script` command array arguments I only see 13 arguments being passed but the VBScript is expecting 14 *(`WshArguments` object collection uses a zero-based index)*.

As [@Yuanyo mentions above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56955533/692942) you are missing `SalesDashload` from the argument list you're passing making it the 14th argument which would map it to `Arg(13)` in the VBScript.

Corrected input would be, something like *(obviously I don't know what your variables are called can only guess or infer based on your existing ones)*;

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {executable, script, fnamePath, loginScr1, stLink1, dashLoad1, role1, consent1, dash1, servMenu1, followUp1, servReq1, SRN1, PoP1, docSubmit1, salesDashLoad1 });
```

You could have captured this in the VBScript by using `Arg.Count` to check you had 14 arguments before continuing the script and maybe [throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254457/692942) if you don't or exiting the script.

```vb
Dim objOutlook, myMail, Arg
Const ExpectArgCount = 14
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

If Arg.Count = ExpectArgCount Then
  myMail.Attachments.Add Arg(0)
  IMED = Arg(1)
  URL = Arg(2)
  dashLoad = Arg(3)
  roles = Arg(4)
  consent = Arg(5)
  dash = Arg(6)
  servMenu = Arg(7)
  folowUp = Arg(8)
  servReq = Arg(9)
  SRN = Arg(10)
  PoP = Arg(11)
  Doc = Arg(12)
  SalesDashLoad = Arg(13)
  MsgBox (SalesDashLoad)
Else
  Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1, "My Application", "Incorrect number of arguments passed")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be the index, you use. You are missing the parameter for SalesDashLoad.

You should have something like:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {executable, script, fnamePath, loginScr1, stLink1, dashLoad1, role1, consent1, servMenu1, followUp1, servReq1, SRN1, PoP1, docSubmit1, salesDLoad1});`

> The Arguments property contains the WshArguments object (a collection of arguments). Use a zero-based index to retrieve individual arguments from this collection.

You can read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84)

Comment: Unfortunately, I struggled to follow your answer because it still only contains 13 arguments when 14 are expected and I think that is because you are missing the `dash` argument from your list.

Comment: Yeah, dash is missing, sorry. IF you add it you should have it working.