# Syntax to determine current error handling method in VBA

Tags: vba

On any given line in my code, can I use Debug.Print() together with some other command to find out what would happen if my code would encounter an error on that line?

Can I use any statement within Debug.Print to find out if the current error handling procedure is to Goto 0, Resume Next or Goto some label?

I'm envisioning something like:

```
Debug.Print(OnErrorMode)
```

I am looking for a way to determine whether a specific line of code that errors will `GoTo 0` (stop and show error), `Resume Next` (skip the line), or `GoTo Label` (jump to Label) given that an `On Error` might be buried somewhere in my code that I cannot find.  Is that possible?

Comment: Your question seems to lack detail, please add some verbiage to your question.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157747/vbscript-using-error-handling) and then frame your question with specific problem

Comment: I edited and tried to explain better.

Comment: @user, I don't think that information is exposed to the script itself. The script engine knows the current error handling mode, obviously, but the script being run is not privy to that.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice! This is the second question you have cleaned up my questions. I'm learning :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In over a decade of using VBA, and VB (5 and 6), I have **never seen a single reference that even remotely suggests that one may be able to determine what error trapping conditions exists.**  While the compiler surely knows, it is not exposed.

It seems to me that your problem may be in regards to how you are structuring your error trapping.

I wrap subroutines in a single On Error Goto statement, located in the same subroutine as the On Error.  I have an exit and when the error occurs, I log what happened so I can fix the bug.  I then can use debug.print or create a string with debugging information that is appended to the log.

```
Sub main()
         On Error GoTo Main_Error
         'Insert Code Here
         Exit Sub
         Main_Error:
         WriteLog Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox ("The program encoutnered an error.")
    End Sub
    Private Sub WriteLog(ErrNum As Integer, ErrDes As String)
        Open "Errors.txt" For Append As #1
        Print #1, Now & "  " & ErrNum & " - " & ErrDes
        Close #1 
    End Sub
```

The second pattern I use is in areas in which there is a good chance that an error may occur, like opening a file (files might be missing), or a database.  then I use the error trapping like a try catch block like so.

```
Private Function LoadFile() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Main_Error
    'Code before a potentially error-prone statement
    On Error Resume Next
    Open "aMissingFile.txt" For Input As #1
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("aMissingFile.txt is missing")
        LoadFile = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo LoadFile_Error
    'The rest of your code
    LoadFile = True
    Exit Function
LoadFile_Error:
    WriteLog Err.Number, Err.Description
    MsgBox ("The program encoutnered an error.")
    LoadFile = False
End Function
```

This makes dealing with errors easier and debugging is as easy as commenting out a single On error statement.  Note that err.number lists the error code return, so you can add logic to handle different types of errors.