# VBScript - Using error handling to determine whether task exists

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

Using the information I learned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446865(v=vs.85).aspx), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157747/vbscript-using-error-handling).
I created the short code below.

When I run the code, and knowingly input a task that exists in the "\" folder of the task scheduler library, I receive the "Task does not exist" msgbox.

I tried including double-quotes around the variables passed into the function, with no success. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strtaskn, strtaskf, sso, result

Call start
Sub start
  strtaskn = ""
  strtaskf = ""
  Do While Len(strtaskn) = 0
    strtaskn = inputbox("Please enter task name to search for:", "Task Exist?")
    If isempty(strtaskn) Then
      WScript.Quit()
    End If
  Loop

  strtaskf = InputBox("Please enter task folder to search in:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Leave blank for default folder", "Task Exist?")
  If Len(strtaskf) = 0 Then strtaskf = "\"
  If IsEmpty(strtaskf) Then
    WScript.Quit()
  End If

  'WScript.Echo strtaskn
  'WScript.Echo strtaskf

  Call taskexist(strtaskn, strtaskf)
End Sub

Function taskexist(taskname, taskfolder)
  Dim rootfolder, task

  Set sso = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
  Call sso.Connect()

  On Error Resume Next
  Set rootfolder = sso.GetFolder(taskfolder)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    result = MsgBox("Task folder does not exist " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to try another search?", vbYesNo+vbCritical, "Task Exist?")
    Select Case result
      Case vbYes
        Err.Clear
        Call start
      Case vbNo
        WScript.Quit()
    End Select
    Err.Clear
  End If

  Set task = rootfolder.GetTasks(taskname)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    result = MsgBox("Task does not exist " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to try another search?", vbYesNo+vbCritical, "Task Exist?")
    Select Case result
      Case vbYes
        Err.Clear
        Call start
      Case vbNo
        WScript.quit()
    End Select
    Err.Clear
  End If
  On Error Goto 0

  result = MsgBox("Task exists" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to try another search?", vbYesNo+vbInformation, "Task Exist?")
End Function
```

***UPDATE***

Using the example shown in my first [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446865(v=vs.85).aspx), I can see an alternative way of achieving the same objective by loading each task found in the collection (by .name) into an array, and comparing the elements to the taskname I'm searching for, or simply by using an iteration loop.

***UPDATE***

Before learning of the error in my original code, thanks to Ansgar. I began scripting the alternative version, which I believe sharing with the community is the right thing to do...

```
option explicit
dim strtaskn, strtaskf, sso, rootfolder, taskcollect, numtasks, intcomp, taskreg, result

call start
sub start
strtaskn=""
strtaskf=""
do while len(strtaskn)=0
strtaskn = inputbox("Please enter task name to search for:","Task Exist?")
if isempty(strtaskn) then
wscript.quit()
end if
loop

strtaskf = inputbox("Please enter task folder to search in:" &vbcrlf&vbcrlf& "Leave blank for default folder","Task Exist?")
if len(strtaskf)=0 then strtaskf = "\"
if isempty(strtaskf) then
wscript.quit()
end if

wscript.echo strtaskn
wscript.echo strtaskf

set sso = createobject("schedule.service")
call sso.connect()

on error resume next
set rootfolder = sso.getfolder(strtaskf)
if err.number <> 0 then
result = msgbox("Task folder does not exist " &err.description &vbcrlf&vbcrlf& "Do you wish to try another search?", vbyesno+vbcritical, "Task Exist?")
select case result
case vbyes
err.clear
call start
case vbno
wscript.quit()
end select
err.clear
end if
on error goto 0

set taskcollect = rootfolder.gettasks(0)

numtasks = taskcollect.count

if numtasks = 0 then 
wscript.echo "No tasks are present in " &strtaskf& " folder"
else
for each taskreg in taskcollect
intcomp = strcomp(strtaskn, taskreg.name, vbtextcompare)
    if intcomp = 0 then
    result = msgbox("Task exists" &vbcrlf&vbcrlf& "Do you wish to try another search?", vbyesno+vbinformation, "Task Exist?")
    select case result
    case vbyes
    call start
    case vbno
    wscript.quit()
    end select  
    end if
next
    result = msgbox("Task does not exist " &vbcrlf&vbcrlf& "Do you wish to try another search?", vbyesno+vbcritical, "Task Exist?")
    select case result
    case vbyes
    call start
    case vbno
    wscript.quit()
    end select
end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Set task = rootfolder.GetTasks(taskname)
> ```

The above statement doesn't do what you think it does. The [`GetTasks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method/property (note the trailing "s") returns all tasks in the given folder. Its parameter is an integer flag indicating whether or not hidden tasks should be included in the returned list (1→include hidden tasks, 0→don't include hidden tasks).

What you actually want is the [`GetTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property:

```
Set task = rootfolder.GetTask(taskname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
service.Connect()
Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")
DetermineName = "\Test Task"
task = rootfolder.GetTask("Test Task")
   if task = DetermineName then
     WScript.Echo "Task Exist"
  else
     WScript.Echo "Not Exist"
  end if
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.