# Error handling in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have to add error handling code in the scriptwrapper file and the code would be in VB Script.
I know try-catch would not work in the VB script. For the Below lines I have to capture the error same like try-catch. So how can I implement this?

```
wrapper.getVariable( "Efficiency" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$21")

wrapper.getVariable( "Plant_Price" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$328")

wrapper.getVariable( "Plant_Price_PerKW" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$331")

wrapper.getVariable( "Net_Present_Value" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$782")
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript -- Using error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157747/vbscript-using-error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

In VB Script error handling is done by using `On Error Resume Next` and then checking the `Err.Number` after your statements.

So:

```
On Error Resume Next

wrapper.getVariable( "Efficiency" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$21")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  Err.Clear
End If



wrapper.getVariable( "Plant_Price" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$328")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  Err.Clear
End If

wrapper.getVariable( "Plant_Price_PerKW" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$331")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  Err.Clear
End If

wrapper.getVariable( "Net_Present_Value" ).value = excel.range("'Cases'!$H$782")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  Err.Clear
End If
```