# How Can I Ignore Internet Errors in a VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, download

I have a vbscript that downloads a file. I need to make it so that if there is no internet that it wont pop up with the error message `The operation timed out`, or `Failed to find the resource specified`. I've tried using `On Error Resume Next`, but alas it does not skip any internet related errors. Any way I can set a timeout or something? It is not a large file, just a 20-line text file. Here is my script:

```
strFileURL = "https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/server/167.114.43.185_25565/json/" 
strHDLocation = "c:\users\public\mc.txt"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript -- Using error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157747/vbscript-using-error-handling)

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` should work all errors in VBScript are caught by `On Error Resume Next` there is nothing else. Are you sure you have set it right?

Comment: It was a repeat error, the script cleared the file, wrote in on Error Resume next, but then cleared it again :/ thanks.

Comment: And not a duplicate XD I tried those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`On Error Resume Next` is the only option for capturing errors, I'm not sure why you say it doesn't work. This works for me;

```
On Error Resume Next

strFileURL = "https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/server/167.114.43.185_25565/json/" 
strHDLocation = "c:\users\public\mc.txt"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
        Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
        objADOStream.Close
        Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
Else
    'Handle the error here.
End If
```

The way `On Error Resume Next` works is as follows;

1. Line triggers an error which is caught by the VBScript runtime.
2. The error is recorded in the `Err` object.
3. The line is skipped and the next statement is run.

This process will continue until an `On Error Goto 0` line is reached at which point the default behaviour resumes.

---

#### Useful Links

- [VBScript — Using error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157785/692942)

Comment: Ill try it again, I might have forgot to restart the script or something idk. Thanks for the help.