# Syntax Error at GoTo on line "On Error GoTo [label]"

Tags: vba, error-handling, vbscript, syntax-error

On compilation, I get a syntax error on the line `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` "Near Column 15" which is the beginning of `GoTo`. I also tried adding a colon to the end of the line (`On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:`) as I've seen some people do, and I get the same error. What is the syntax error that I'm missing?

#### Subroutine:

```vb
Sub HandleAnError()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim X
    X = 1/0
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, I tried it and I get the same error. Updated the question.

Comment: Copy and pasting your code into a general module in excel runs fine. Where are you running it?

Comment: It's compiling and running in an independent program. I don't have the details of what compiler it's using, but that may be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about VBA? Not VB.Net? Does this code live within Excel or Word or similar?

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was VBA. It's not within a Microsoft program. I guess I didn't know the distinction. Pretty new to this language, and was trying to edit something that already existed. Try Catch hasn't worked either.. -_-

Comment: If you even don't know which language you are using, how can we help you. Where do you edit your code? How do you call it? Where does the compiler error come from?

Comment: @FunThomas I edit in Notepad++, I call it as `HandleAnError()` on one line, and the compiler error comes from a janky application my work uses that compiles and runs the source code every time the application starts.

Comment: Or interpreted rather than compiled. This is new terminology to me. I believe it's interpreted based on how the application runs and can be changed while it's running. VBA is interpreted, so this is VBA to my knowledge.

Comment: Probably you deal with VB.Script (something really different than VBA!!!). Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/157785/7599798

Comment: @FunThomas You're right, this fixed my problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim X = 1/0
```

should be

```
Dim X

X=1/0
```

Comment: I get the same error when I fixed that.

Comment: Don't think this should have been downvoted. It solves the problem as posted - OP has since moved the goalposts.

Comment: @SJR That wasn't the error that I was asking about. If I fixed the error I was asking about, then I would get an error about this, but I never got an error about this...

Comment: If you put your code into the VBE with this amendment the code runs as expected. Perhaps you should close the question and start again.

Comment: This answer didn't answer my question as it was when it was first opened. It was a simple syntax error unrelated to my question.